# Getting a 404 error occurred "The requested URL could not be matched by routing" in ZF2

Tags: zend-framework2

Please be advise on "Getting a 404 error occurred "The requested URL could not be matched by routing" in ZF2".

The section that is giving me trouble is this:

```
'router'          => array(
    'routes' => array(
        'album' => array(
            'type'    => 'Segment',
            'options' => array(
                'route'       => '/album[/:action][/:id]',
                'constraints' => array(
                    'action' => '[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9_-]*',
                    'id'     => '[0-9]+',
                ),
                'defaults'    => array(
                    '__NAMESPACE__' => 'Album\Controller',
                    'controller'    => 'Album\Controller\Album',
                    'action'        => 'index',
                ),
            ),
        ),
    ),
),
```

Comment: My advice is to check your route configuration, since the error is telling you that a route does not exist matching the url

Comment: Can you post your routing configuration?

Comment: Nency, we need much more information. What URL are you trying to access from your browser? Furthermore, when you define a `__NAMESPACE__` you only need the ControllerAlias `Album`, it will the automatically be concatenated

Comment: Nency, the most important thing besides the route config, is the url you use to test. What url have you tried to access the page?

Answer (score 0):

You route is right! (Don't need NameSpace with your default)

```
// The following section is new and should be added to your file
'router' => array(
    'routes' => array(
        'album' => array(
            'type'    => 'segment',
            'options' => array(
                'route'    => '/album[/:action][/:id]',
                'constraints' => array(
                    'action' => '[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9_-]*',
                    'id'     => '[0-9]+',
                ),
                'defaults' => array(
                    'controller' => 'Album\Controller\Album',
                    'action'     => 'index',
                ),
            ),
        ),
    ),
),
'view_manager' => array(
    'template_path_stack' => array(
        'album' => __DIR__ . '/../view',
    ),
),
```

You have to add your module in application.config.php (which you are saying you done it.)

```
// This should be an array of module namespaces used in the application.
'modules' => array(
    'Application',
    'Album'
),
```

Answer (score 0):

1) in type use "segment" instead of "Segment".
2) in the route
use
route'    => '/album[/][:action][/:id]',

instead of 
'route'       => '/album[/:action][/:id]',

3)

Answer (score -1):

add

```
// getAutoloaderConfig() and getConfig() methods here
    public function getAutoloaderConfig() { 
        return array( 
            'Zend\Loader\StandardAutoloader' => array( 
                'namespaces' => array( 
                    __NAMESPACE__ => __DIR__ . '/src/' . __NAMESPACE__, 
                ), 
            ), 
        ); 
    } 

    public function getConfig() { 
        return include __DIR__ . '/config/module.config.php'; 
    }
```

Module.php